# Flutter app with cloud_firestore,firebase_messaging not working in ios

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Application woking in Android but not working in ios, it displays following error

> 6.14.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist. Configuring the default Firebase app...  path:
>   satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0 Configured the default
>   Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied),
>   interface: en0
>   6.14.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60107000 started
>   6.14.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
>   6.14.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS025036] App Delegate Proxy is disabled
>
> *** First throw call stack: (     0  CoreFoundation           0x00007fff23c7127e **exceptionPreprocess + 350  1  libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48  2  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff23c70ff8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88    3 
>   Foundation             0x00007fff256e9c1a -[NSAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166   4  Runner
>   0x000000010f041364
>   _ZN8firebase9firestore4util16ObjcThrowHandlerENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE
>   + 356     5  Runner               0x000000010f040983 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util5ThrowENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3**<…>

**Flutter Doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/harishvekariya/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (4 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/harishvekariya/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/harishvekariya/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3, Build version 11C29
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.0.beta.2
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 8 Plus • C215DD89-A799-490A-9A30-61891807F940 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)
• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```